# Traceback and TypeError on Python import of excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am getting the following error on the code below :

- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Personal Files/Technical Development/PycharmProjects/Call Center Headcount Model/Call Center Headcount Model.py", line 12, in 
  historical_start_date = work_rules.iloc(4, 2)
- TypeError: **call**() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I am trying to assign a cell value in excel to a variable in Python through pandas. i.e. Historical_start_date = work_rules.loc(4,2)

Any idea why this is?

Code:

```
 work_rules = pd.read_excel(
            'D:\\Personal Files\\Technical Development\\PycharmProjects\\Call Center Headcount Model\\Call Center Work Rules.xlsx',
            sheet_name='Inputs')
        
        historical_start_date = work_rules.iloc(4, 2)
        
        print(historical_start_date)
```

Comment: What is "enter code here"? I think you nee to get rid of it.

Comment: I changed that but it isnt part of the code in my actual script.

Comment: `iloc` uses square brackets for indexing.

Comment: `historical_start_date = work_rules.iloc[4, 2]`

Comment: you are wonderful. If you want to put it in an answer I can mark it as correct so you get the credit.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Iloc documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). You're supplying variables as if it is a method. I'm not sure what you want to do exactly but it seems to me that you need to replace the parenthesis after iloc with brackets.